# Try to change the frame of UIImageView but it doesn't work according to the code

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, resize

I made a subclass of UIImageView. I use its function `setupView()` to setup each DirectionView object's frame in viewDidLoad() and it works perfectly. But when I reset a DirectionView object's frame using the same function when a button is triggered, the new frame value is not what I expected.

The x, y, width, and height value shown in debug area are all correct. However, the frame value I print out using `print("Original frame: \(self.frame)")` shows a different set of value.

Why does this happen? And how to fix it?

```
class DirectionView: UIImageView {
    
    override init(image: UIImage?) {
        super.init(image: image)

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)

    }
    
    func setupView(_ degree: Double, showSigInfo: Bool) {
        
        let rotationAngle = degree.toRadians
        var height: Double = 375 / 2
            
        let width = height / 47 * 37
        let x = 375 / 2  - width / 2
        let y = 0.0
        self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)

        print("Original frame: \(self.frame)")
        self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0))
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: rotationAngle)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: add this line before setting frame : ```self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true```

Comment: Hi @RajaKishan, thanks for the advice, but it doesn't change the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to the `anchor point`. According to docs, "All geometric manipulations to the view occur about the specified point" (referring to the anchor point). When you rotate the image, and then resize it, the anchor point is not well located so, the final height and width aren't the ones you specified.

I avoided doing all the geometric calculations that would've led to the correct location of the anchor point (or the correct height and width). But, here's one solution:

1. Remove the code line `self.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0))`
2. Before setting the frame, that is before the line `self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)`. Add the following line: `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.0) {self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0)}`

That should do the work.

Why it works? The default value of the anchor point is (0.5,0.5), which gives the correct resizing when the image is on its standard position (rotation = 0). So, the solution rotates the image to its standard position, resizes it, and then rotates it to the angle you want. The device does it fast enough so that the user doesn't notices the double rotation.